# Есть ли встроенная функция выполняющая динамическое выражение?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть ли в БД встроенная функция, которая работает подобным образом:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IFTrueValue(iValue NUMBER, sOper VARCHAR2, iTest NUMBER, iTrue NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
    bCond BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
        SELECT CASE WHEN '||iValue||sOper||iTest||' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        FROM dual' INTO bCond;
    RETURN CASE bCond
           WHEN TRUE THEN iTrue
           ELSE iValue END;
END;
/
SELECT IFTrueValue(Mod(20, 20), '=', 0, 20) res FROM dual; -- вывод 20
SELECT IFTrueValue(Mod(25, 20), '=', 0, 20) res FROM dual; -- вывод 5: Mod(25, 20)
```

Функция работает, но интересно, есть ли встроенный в БД функционал.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle test function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63505413) от участника [@Michał Barbarski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14137368/micha%c5%82-barbarski)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63505413

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоватся встроеными функциями [xmlCast()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLCAST.html#GUID-06563B93-1247-4F0C-B6BE-42DB3B1DB069) и [xmlQuery()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLQUERY.html#GUID-9E8D3220-2CF5-4C63-BDC2-0526D57B9CDB) для этой цели.

Вот  воспроизводимый пример с тестовыми дданными:

```
with t(iValue, sOper, iTest, iTrue) as (
    select Mod(20, 20), '=', 0, 20 from dual union all
    select Mod(25, 20), '=', 0, 20 from dual union all
    select Mod(25, 20), '>', 0, 13 from dual
)
select t.*, xmlcast (xmlquery (('
    if ($iValue '||sOper||' $iTest) then $iTrue else $iValue')
    passing iValue as "iValue", iTest  as "iTest", iTrue  as "iTrue"
    returning content) as number) result
from t
/
```

Результат:

```
    IVALUE SOPER      ITEST      ITRUE     RESULT
---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
         0 =              0         20         20
         5 =              0         20          5
         5 >              0         13         13
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63505745) от участника [@Sayan Malakshinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429100/sayan-malakshinov)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Выражение `WHEN '||iValue||sOper||iTest||' THEN` как минимум должно использовать переменные связывания, а не конкантинировать значения. Для условных операторов это невозможно. Но их то как раз не так много, поэтому наиболее эффективно отказаться от динамического выполнения выражений, а использовать просто `CASE`.

Вот пример того, что имею ввиду:

```
with function testExpression (
    expr number, testoper char, value number, intruth number) return number is
    function raiseIllegalOper return char is
    begin raise_application_error (-20000, 'illegal test operator '||testoper);
    end;
begin
    return case testoper 
        when '=' then case expr = value when true then intruth else expr end 
        when '>' then case expr > value when true then intruth else expr end
        -- when ... итд для ['<', '<=', '>=', '!='] 
        else raiseIllegalOper end;
end;
t (expr, testoper, value, intruth) as (
    select mod (20, 20), '=', 0, 20 from dual union all
    select mod (25, 20), '=', 0, 20 from dual union all
    select mod (25, 20), '>', 0, 13 from dual
)
select t.*, testExpression (expr, testoper, value, intruth) result
from t
/
```

Результат:

```
      EXPR TESTOPER      VALUE    INTRUTH     RESULT
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         0 =                 0         20         20
         5 =                 0         20          5
         5 >                 0         13         13
```